# Trim whitespace (trailing newline) at the end of included Twig template

Tags: twig, removing-whitespace, trailing-whitespace

I’m trying to include a Twig template inside another, but there is undesirable whitespace which is caused by the trailing newline in the included template.

My use case is that the include takes place mid-sentence, just before a comma, and I don’t want any whitespace before the comma.

Base template:

```
Né le {{ include("date.html.twig", {date: date}) }}, décédé le…
```

Included template:

```
<time datetime="...">
  {{- date.format() -}}
</time>
```

Desired result :

```
Né le 6 mai 1977, décédé le…
```

Actual result :

```
Né le 6 mai 1977 , décédé le…
```

I can confirm the trailing newline is the cause of the issue, but removing it is not a viable solution to me since most tools are configured to add it if it’s missing.

Is there any way to trim this trailing newline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution while writing the question:

Ending the included template with a Twig tag seems to be enough. So I ended up wrapping the content in a `spaceless` filter:

```
{% apply spaceless %}
<time datetime="...">
  {{- date.format() -}}
</time>
{% endapply %}
```

Technically using `{% if true %} … {%- endif %}` also works, but is much less understandable.

`-` modifiers are still needed inside `<time>` because `spaceless` only removes whitespace between HTML tags, not inside.